# Is that possible to use different network adapters among real pc and virtual machine

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a PC in my office, it only connect to the LAN in our company, If I want to access internet, I need to use another computer. It's very inconvenient. But we have wifi in our office, So I am thinking maybe I can buy a usb wireless adapter, then install a virtual machine on my PC, then use the wireless adapter connect to internet in virtual machine, while I can still work in the LAN outside the virtual machine.

It's currently only a idea, I need to know if that's possible first.

sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible and called `USB passthrough`. You could read the relevant info in the [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp46691715306272)

But if I were you I would check if this compiles with your company's security policies e.t.c. first